# How to deal with left skewed data and generalized linear models

Tags: glmm, skewness

I am trying to look at individual variation in Pielou's evenness of parasite communities. I have a study in which ~60 animals were sampled nine times (every two-three months for two years). Samples (blood samples) were then processed using Illumina MiSeq and we obtained relative abundance of each hemo-parasite within the community. I then used relative abundance of hemoparasites to calculate Pielou's evenness for each sample.

I want to use generalized linear mixed models to calculate between animal variation (Vg) and within animal variation (Vr) of evenness. Thus, I would fit the model: Pielou's evenness ~ 1 + (1|Animal.ID).

However, Pielou's evenness is left skewed. What is the best way to handle left skewed data? Pielou's evenness is on a scale of 0-1 so, as I am just interested in variation between samples, can I flip the data to be right skewed through 1 - Pielou's evenness and the fit a linear mixed model using a log transformation of (1 - Pielou's evenness)?

Is there an alternative approach to assessing between individual and within individual variation in Pielou's evenness besides this glmm approach?

Comment: Maybe try a Beta mixed model, in `glmmTMB` or `brms` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your outcome is in the (0, 1) scale, you could analyze it with a Beta distribution and hence fit a Beta mixed effects model. You can, for example, do that using the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package in R. For more details on how to fit a Beta mixed effects model, have a look at the vignette [User-Defined Family Objects](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Custom_Models.html).